How can I find patent applications, not the granted patent documents?
I need to find the patent applications for some patents, but they have all been granted so the original applications do not come up.

This is pretty easy. I'll use a patent found in Google Patents as an example. Let's say you find a patent like this one: US8346531B2. On the right side of the window you'll see a list of legal events. One should be something like "2010-05-06 Publication of US20100114555A1". US20100114555A1 is the application number. You can just click on that number and Google Patents will open it up. For US patents, application document numbers start with the year and usually end with "A1".
If you want all the documents related to a specific US patent, you can always get them from the USPTO Patent Center.

@Lindsay Kupka. You can also see any amendments and all communications between the office and applicant.
